# App Inventor can't connect to AI2 Companion (progress bar stuck at 92%)

Tags: android

I am not able to connect MIT App Inventor 2 to the AI2 Companion on my phone. The progress bar comes up and sends assets to the companion but it hangs up at 92%.

I have included a speech recognizer in my project but as its not available in the emulator, I really need to connect App Inventor to my phone.

I tried steps mentioned in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mitappinventortest/FdUzWNk-EZA/9Mnzn01fBQAJ) but it wasn't useful.
I reinstalled the companion several times.
Please check out this.

[image].

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because your app is too big for your device to handle at once. Try making a new app with a simple function and see if it connects. If it does, this is your issue.
I was just reading something about this that made sense, here on Google groups: [AI2 Companion it´s not working](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/mw6qgnFLr3w), as well as the various other possibilities discussed.
Also, check what browser are you using. When I tried Google Chrome, it instantly worked for me!